# Problem with Cartesian product and dimension for beginners

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose I have:
$$A=\{(0,0)\}$$
$$B=\mathbb{R}^2$$

The dimension of Cartesian product $A \times B$ is
$$ dim (A \times B)=0+2=2$$
because the dimension of one-point-set is $0$.

But if I take one element from $A \times B$, for example $(0,0,1,1)$, it is from $\mathbb{R}^4$, so the dimension of the product would be wrong.

Where am I making a mistake? Thank you for help.

Comment: Since $A\times B\setminus\{(0,0,1,1)\}$ is not a vector space, what do you mean when you write about its dimension?

Comment: $(0, 0, 1, 1) \notin A \times B$, don't you mean $((0, 0), 1, 1)$? Also, when you say dimension, do you mean the amount of vectors in a basis of $A \times B$ or $n$ where we write an element of $A \times B$ as $(a_1, ..., a_n)$?

Comment: if you put the values together you can build a vector that lies in $\mathbb R^4$, but maybe is limited (depending on which spaces A and B are) which of the vectors in $\mathbb R^4$ could be built in that way?

Answer (score 2):

The dimension is actually defined by number of linearly independent  basis describing that space. The quadruples you defined can be described as following:
$$X=\lbrace{(a,b,c,d)|a=b=0,c,d\in \Bbb R^2}\rbrace$$
A linearly independent vector basis as a subset of $\Bbb R^4$ can be defined as:
$$v_1=(0,0,0,1)$$
$$v_2=(0,0,1,0)$$
Obviously $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent and the fully describe the defined subspace of $\Bbb R^4$. As an another example take a plane in $\Bbb R^3$. While the members of that plane are triplets that's trivial that a plane is 2-dimensional so our justification makes sense.